# Using pressKey to simulate typeText is not producing desired result

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

Because as an input field on a site I am testing was created by the site developer with a random class, `typeText` will not work since Testcafe does not recognize it as a valid input field.

As a result, I am trying to use `pressKey` to simulate `typeText` to enter a string into the input field.

Unfortunately, the result is not what I was hoping for. Using `.pressKey('L P')` should result in **`LP`** appearing in the search box but instead **`LPL`** appears.

How do I solve this issue? I have no idea why there is another `L` appearing where it should not.

For reference, using `typeText` causes this to show as an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: this.ui.searchBox.val is not a function`

For further reference the selector looks like this:

`#modals > div.selectra-dropdown > div > div.search > input[type="zax"]`

On querying what the hell a "zax" was, I was told by the site developer that it was a made up classname used as a workaround for some problem and I am stuck with it.

Comment: what would help me personally, it's to see the html identifier like HTMLobject =Selector("how-you-identity") of the object you want to interact to plus the entire await.t.typeText(HTMLobject); also, a printscreen from the chrome dev tools, with the object you want to interact with

Comment: The HTML identifier is: `<input type="zax">`

Comment: I used a separate page to create selectors: `this.empty_lp_group_search = Selector('#modals > div.selectra-dropdown > div > div.search > input[type="zax"]');
`

Comment: The screenshot of the console: https://imgur.com/nPqQlWE

Comment: The process I follow with the keypress is: `    .click(lp.empty_lp_group_select)
    .pressKey('L P')` the selector being `empty_lp_group_select` which is defined in `this.empty_lp_group_select = Selector('#link-resources > div.modal-host > div.modal-element.modal-container > div > div.modal-body > div.form-container > div > div.lp-chooser-container > div > div > div > div > div');`

Answer (score 3):

Likely it means that TestCafe can't properly simulate keyboard events for your page. Please create a [bug report](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) and provide a page and a test that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately NDA will not allow me to share such in depth details. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: Could you prepare a sample page that contains only the search box? Or specify what libraries or frameworks you use to create it: React, Vue, Angular?

Answer (score 2):

TBH, I really hope you find your answer, but due to that `type=[zax]`, for me its impossible to help here;
but nevertheless, you could simplify your code and try something like

1. *replace this here* `this.empty_lp_group_search = Selector('#modals > div.selectra-dropdown > div > div.search > input[type="zax"]');` *with* `this.empty_lp_group_search = Selector('#modals input[type="zax"]');`
2. *maybe also this* `this.empty_lp_group_select = Selector('#link-resources > div.modal-host > div.modal-element.modal-container > div > div.modal-body > div.form-container > div > div.lp-chooser-container > div > div > div > div > div');` *with this* `this.empty_lp_group_select = Selector('#link-resources div.nth(12)');`; this last one is based on this link here https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#nth

Comment: Thanks for that! Any idea as to why keyPress returns an extra letter? It basically repeats the first key used again. I will get to work with your recommendations immediately.

Comment: even tho` it won't solve your problem ,but still, makes the code a little bit clearer